# Not sure why my question is closed

Tags: discussion, support, questions, specific-question

The question: *[Intergrate JSONEditor in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403053/intergrate-jsoneditor-in-asp-net-mvc)*

Why did my question get closed?

I'm expecting a similar answer like the first one posted. If it's been closed without looking at it, clearly shouldn't this be reported whereas I believe the Stack Overflow community is to share knowledge on programming and learning and falsely closing puts a barrier to this?

Comment: One possible rationale for choosing the close reason "_Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more_" may be because the question ends with "_Is it possible to do so and may I know of any useful resource to look at?_"

Comment: 'I believe the stack overflow community is to share knowledge on programming and learning'...nearly.  The precise aim of SO is explained in the tour and help.

Comment: 'f it's been closed without looking at it' why would you, or anyone, think that was the case?

Comment: 'shouldn't this be reported'....to whom?

Comment: It was closed because it's a poorly written question, in addition to the fact that it asks for off-site recommendations. A review of the SO help pages might be of use.

Comment: Why is the question too broad? It sounds like a common problem anyone with some experience in that particular area would immediately recognise.

Comment: What does *"the first one posted"* refer to?

Answer (score 18):

That question is asking too much of us. Posting two screenshots and a text blurb that roughly describes your requirement is not a reasonably answerable question.

We would have to start explaining that the execution of a Node app is wildly different from how an ASP.NET MVC app works. It is unclear what you mean by "get the view of JSONEditor view in the ASP.NET MVC project". Do you realize you'll need both Kestrel and Node running, or at least a means to have Kestrel execute the javascript that is meant to run server side? If it is just showing, did you try an IFrame? That is not ASP.NET or Node, just HTML. If you got it viewed, how do you plan to interact with it?

There is too much that is unclear and explaining all the intricacies that come with these kinds of integrations requires a lot of paragraphs, if not a book.

You don't need an answer, you need a brainstorm in front of a whiteboard. And once you've settled on a path that might solve the issue at hand you need to get an implementation started. Just having two project folders checked-out and working isn't enough to count as an integration implementation.

Once you have code, markup, and a structure that functions, you might be closer to a question about an actual, concrete implementation issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Do more research first, or try a forum, chat, or discord if you need one-on-one exploration of options you have.

Comment: As one of the close-voters, I was 'preparing' an answer ... but you saved me the trouble (and posted an excellent explanation). Thanks.